# Strange situation with a down voted answer

Tags: support, voting, down-votes

I made a comment for an answer that had a mistake. Someone else down voted that answer, but the guy with the answer assumed that was me who down voted. After that the guy corrected the answer somehow and maybe waited for the down vote to be removed.

The downvote was not removed and the guy as revenge down voted two of my questions. Is there something I can do?

The problem is that the down voted answer was removed.

Comment: That's why I usually say, "I didn't downvote, but this is wrong because..." - nothing like getting framed...

Comment: In short, there's nothing you can do. Moderators can't reverse votes (although they can forward the information to developers who *can*). 2 downvotes is too few to trigger the reversal script. So either you eat it, or hope a developer will care enough to take a closer look at it.

Comment: eating it :) and hoping that something can be done to prevent such problems in the future

Comment: @Mysticial This is why I say "I didn't downvote" even if I did.

Comment: You are just going to have to suck it up. It's just one of those things that you have to accept. Occupational hazard. I'm sure you'll pick up a couple of sympathy up votes from this question though. But just don't worry about it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I already did. Someone up voted these 2 questions. I feel embarrassed now.

Comment: It always feels bad when people down vote you. You just have to learn to cope with it. If the down votes are fair and valid, improve your post. If the down votes are obviously malicious, ignore it. Don't let it get you down.

Comment: When that happens, my standard response is: "I didn't downvote, and here's my downvote now to prove it". It's not the nicest thing in the world, but it works, the OP immediately realizes how much of an ass they were being to someone who had only tried to help them.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a comment that you did not downvote.

And if you feel you got serial downvoted then wait a day. If it does not get reversed automatically then flag one of the downvoted posts *for moderator attention*. They can handle such cases.

In the end 2 downvotes are 4 reputation points. Like others commented: You may also just let it be. Especially with almost 4000 rep you already have.

Comment: The problem is that the down voted answer was removed.

Comment: You don't have to flag that post. Flag one of **your** posts that got serial downvoted. In the flag comment you can add a link to the question with the removed answer.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. No big deal. But I was shocked about that guy reaction and felt that I should do something.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way around this in my opinion. If someone claims you were the downvoter, and you were not, then you can state you were not in comments.

If that does not deter them, and if their answer does not in your opinion deserve a down vote, you can consider upvoting it as the ultimate evidence and commenting +1. This will show beyond a doubt that you were not the downvoter and should remove any animosity involved.